# How to count rows based on the variable position in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, minimum

I have a data frame that looks like that : (the treatment has multiple possibily of character variable, I just simplified for the question)

```
ID              Position            Treatment
--20AxECvv-         0           A
--20AxECvv-         -1          A
--20AxECvv-         -2          A
--h9INKewQf-        0           A
--h9INKewQf-        -1          B
--h9INKewQf-        -2          B
--h9INKewQf-        -3          B
--h9INKewQf-        -4          B
--h9INKewQf-        -5          B
--h9INKewQf-        -6          B
--h9INKewQf-        -7          B
zZU7a@8jN           0           B
QUeSNEXmdB          0           C
QUeSNEXmdB          -1          C
qu72Ql@h79          0           C
```

I just want to keep the treatment of the minimum position for each ID with Python.

The result would be :

```
 ID              Position            Treatment
--20AxECvv-         -2          A
--h9INKewQf-        -7          B
zZU7a@8jN           0           B
QUeSNEXmdB          -1          C
qu72Ql@h79          0           C
```

I am a beginner, I think I have to use a groupby and filter by the minimum position but I have any idea how to write it. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also sort your dataframe using `df.sort_values` and drop duplicates using `df.drop_duplicates`:

```
In [795]: df.sort_values('Position').drop_duplicates('ID')
Out[795]: 
              ID  Position Treatment
10  --h9INKewQf-        -7         B
2    --20AxECvv-        -2         A
13    QUeSNEXmdB        -1         C
11     zZU7a@8jN         0         B
14    qu72Ql@h79         0         C
```

Comment: By doing this, I have some ID that are duplicated with the  last position for different Treatment.

Comment: @AnnaCarrere Okay, the order is different, but it's exactly the rows you want.

Comment: Still have the same problem when I apply it in the whole dataframe and I don't understand why

Comment: @AnnaCarrere Are you sure? You're running the second solution right? I removed the first one.

Comment: I just put a simplifyed data frame. I just want the list of the ID (unique value for each) with the corresponding treatment based on the first position (ie the smallest one)

Comment: @AnnaCarrere Okay. I think, this time, I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

using groupby and min

```
df.groupby('ID').min()
```